# Best practices for sharing data between android apps

Tags: java, android, android-intent, sharedpreferences, android-contentprovider

I need to share data between two android apps that are on the same phone without using the internet. The data I want to share includes a several key value pairs of different data types. The options I am aware of are:

1. Using intents - [Send](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html) and [Receive](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html). But the typical examples
   for intents do not involve these use cases. Intents seems more
   suited for sharing data of a particular mime type or launch apps (or
   let users choose from) to handle the data being shared.
2. Sharing the [SharedPreferences](http://chrisrisner.com/Accessing-the-Shared-Preferences-of-a-Different-Application-in-Android). However the MODE_WORLD_READABLE
   or MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE flags required for this have been deprecated
   post API 17.
3. [Broadcast Receivers](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html) - But I'm not exactly listening to events.
   I want to use a request/response cycle.
4. [Content Providers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html). This is great except for the fact that I
   need to store the data in a database in the app sharing the data. If I have key, value pairs
   where the value can be of different data types, this makes the data
   table a bit cumbersome. Is there a better way to do this with
   content providers?

Which is the best technique to adopt?

Comment: use ContentProvider, you dont have to store the data in a sqlite db, you can use anything e.g. SharedPreferences

Comment: Does the data need to be persistent? or can it just be stored in memory (and will be gone when both apps shutdown or the phone is rebooted)

Comment: The data needs to be persistent. But out of curiosity, what were you thinking of if it can be held in memory or in transient storage?

Comment: @pskink - Any example how I can use SharedPreferences with a ContentProvider properly? AFAIK, the ContentResolver returns a cursor when we do a query in a normal situation.

Comment: return a MatrixCuesor in ContentProvider.query() merhod

Answer (score 1):

I created a small library that makes it simple to share `SharedPreferences` from one app to another in a `READ ONLY` fashion using `ContentProvider`.

Described it here - https://github.com/ratpik/android-sharedpreferences-api/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 0):

You can set up Broadcast Reciever on one end to listen for particular intent type. And broadcast intents from first application with data held in extras. You can send whole objects via intent using parcerable approach.

More about parcerable approach can be found [here](https://github.com/thecodepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-Parcelable)